# Cast to datetime only if its a date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with DateFrom column

[image]

it's an nvarchar col in the col I have data like that

```
01
02
10/10/2020
04
```

some strings and some DateTime values
I need to cast it to DateTime but only if it's a date if not then pull out the value like it is can is this possible?
thanks ...

Comment: Have you tried TRY_CAST and TRY_CONVERT-functions ?

Comment: hi yes but its not working pichos of this values 01-02 I think

Comment: No one can read your mind or see your screen or examine your database. Phrase like "not working" mean nothing to anyone. Use TRY_CONVERT with the desired style will work but may not produce the results you expect for many reasons. Post details what what query you tried that "did not work" and how you know that along with sample data that demonstrates your problem. And why do you convert to datetime when it seems your strings have only dates (at best)?

Comment: i added 2 pic one it the query and the second is the result in the result I need the values will pull out like dd/MM/yyyy is its a DateTime value if not then the value need to stay like it is

Comment: That's because `'01-02'` isn't a date, @TechMan . Dates have a Day, Month, Year parts; you have 2 parts there (and it's impossible to identify which 2 as well).

Comment: This can get tricky. Is `10/11/21` a date? If so which one? Is `01/02/2021` February 1 or January 2? What formats are possible? Your screenshot shows `Oct` which is a month name abbreviation that would be recognized in a session with English settings and not regognized in a German session for instance. Why do you have a table with such fuzzy column anyway? Such data should not exist in a proper database.

Comment: A value of ``'01-02'`` could be 01 Feb (of what year?), 02 Jan (of what year?), (What day) of Feb 1901, (What day) of Feb 2001, (What day) of Jan 1902, (What day) of Jan 2002. It could even be something "silly" like day 1 of 1902, day 2 of 1901, day 1 of 2002, day 2 of 2001, the first day (of which month) of 1902/2002 or the 2nd day (of what month) of 1902/2002.

Comment: Stop wasting time. Your goal is likely impossible now that it seems you have strings containing different date formats. You simply do not have the skills to address this alone and you need to gather your group to have a much bigger discussion about your actual goal, the decisions that led to this predicament, and the most effective way to address them.

Answer (score 1):

a Simple Try cast should do the job here

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Val NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES('1'),('2'),('10/10/2020'),('04')


SELECT
    *,
    TRY_CAST(Val AS DATE)
    FROM @Table
```

Results

[image]

Comment: hi but i still need the 1-2-04 in the same col

Comment: @TechMan: This is not possible. You want to cast the string to a datetime. 1 is not a datetime, so what datetime other then null would you display? Maybe you really want to cast to a well-formatted string instead (say 'yyyy-mm-dd')? But as mentioned in the request comments, there shouldn't be such a column in your database to start with, so the better option may be to rethink your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  It uses a CASE statement to check whether or not the value is a valid date and if so casts it to DATETIME, then converts it to VARCHAR (so dates and other values can be returned as the same column).

You can find other datetime to string styles here if you need them formatted differently:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Dt NVARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @TempTable
VALUES('1'),('2'),('10/10/2020'),('04'),('Jun 27 2021 12:22AM'),('Oct 12 2021 8:31PM')


SELECT
*,
CASE WHEN ISDATE(Dt) = 1 THEN Convert(VARCHAR, CAST(Dt AS DATETIME), 120) ELSE Dt END
FROM @TempTable
```

[image]

Comment: hi i get this err : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Are you using the temp table @TempTable I used in the code snippet or are you trying to run it against your database table?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check this with the case statement.
Postgres example

```
select case when '12/12/2021' ~ '\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}' then 'this is the date' ELSE 'this is a string' end;

->this is the date
```

```
select case when 'some text' ~ '\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}' then 'this is the date' ELSE 'this is a string' end;

->this is a string
```

so you can use it like this

```
select case when fild_01 ~ '\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}' then TO_DATE(fild_01,'DD/MM/YYYY')::text ELSE fild_01 end from test_table;
```

as you can see, case construction can't generalize two different types of data, so I had to convert them to the same type of text

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TRY_CONVERT` function, [with style `107`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 'Jun 27 2021 12:22AM', 107)
```

| Result |
| --- |
| 2021-06-27 00:22:00.000 |

This returns a null if the value is not a date

Answer (score 0):

You can choose according to your needs.

When you want to set default value:

```
SELECT IIF(ISDATE(Val) = 1 , Val,'YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE')
```

Whent default value not matter (It will be NULL):

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(NULL AS DATE)
```